# Backlog上のgitリポジトリからファイルを一括で取得したい

Tags: git

Backlogのgitリポジトリからファイルを一括で取得したいのですが、Backlogの性質上不可能なようです。
HTTPS の場合は `https://--.git` のようなURLが表示されていますが、このURLからリモートリポジトリの取得からプルリクエストすることは可能でしょうか。

Comment: 「gitファイル」とは何のことを指してらっしゃいますか？　Backlog 上のリモートリポジトリにおいて git で管理されているファイルたち、のことでしょうか。

Comment: その通りです。Backlog 上のリモートリポジトリにおいて git ファイルのことです。

Comment: 「ファイルの取得」と最後に書かれた「プルリクエスト」は別の話になると思うので、質問も分けた方がよさそうな気がします。

Answer (score 1):

単に `git clone` をなさりたいのかなと思いました。

リポジトリへのアクセス権があるのであれば、その HTTPS の URL を使ってコンソールで `git clone` することができます。

例：

```sh
git clone https://nulab.backlog.jp/git/BLG/tutorial.git    # ←URLを適宜書き換えてください
```

git 用の GUI クライアントをお使いなのであれば、そのクライアントの clone 機能を使ってクローンできます。

Backlog が提供しているチュートリアルへのリンクも貼っておきます：[リモートリポジトリをクローンする](https://backlog.com/ja/git-tutorial/intro/14/)。
環境を選択すれば、コンソールの例と GUI クライアントの例を見れます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらを参考にしてみます。

Answer (score 0):

恐らく GitHub での [リリース](https://help.github.com/ja/github/administering-a-repository/creating-releases) 機能のような、リポジトリの内容をzipファイル等で取得することをしたいのだろうと思います。

- Backlog のヘルプセンターにも要望が挙がっていますが、いまだヘルプに明記されていないということは未実装なのでしょう。

  [Gitリポジトリのダウンロード機能が欲しい | Backlog ヘルプセンター](https://support-ja.backlog.com/hc/ja/community/posts/360018603634)
- 代わりの方法として、`git archive` を使う方法が考えられます。既にローカルにクローン済みならコマンドでアーカイブを作成出来ます。

  [Git リポジトリの内容を zip ファイルにする - Qiita](https://qiita.com/usamik26/items/9a2d14aea30cb01a60c6)

  ```
  $ git archive HEAD --output=/path/to/repo.zip
  ```

  もしくはクローンせずに最新の情報だけ引っ張って来てアーカイブにする方法もあるようです。

  [git archive を用いて clone せずに特定のディレクトリだけを取得する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Yuki-Inoue/items/b2eae79eae37e8c41b31)